# Proj of Almost Same Graded Rings are Isomorphic (Exercise from Vakil's FOAG)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, schemes, projective-schemes

I'm trying to solve Exercise 6.4.F from Vakil's *FOAG*:

> **6.4.F.** Exᴇʀᴄɪsᴇ.$\quad$Show that if $R_\bullet$ and $S_\bullet$ are the same finitely generated graded rings except in a finite number of nonzero degrees (make this precise!), then $\operatorname{Proj} R_\bullet \cong \operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet$.

First, I think what Vakil means when he says *same finitely generated rings except in a finite number of nonzero degrees* is that $R_{\bullet}$ and $S_{\bullet}$ have all their homogeneous pieces ($R_n$ and $S_n$ respectively) the same, except for finitely many $n$. Could someone please verify if this is right?

Second, assuming the above, here's how I would solve this exercise: since $S_n$ and $R_n$ are identical for all large $n$, if we consider $m \gg 0$, then we have that $R_{m\bullet}$ and $S_{m\bullet}$ are identical. Thus $\operatorname{Proj} S_{m\bullet}\cong\operatorname{Proj} R_{m\bullet}$. But Exercise 6.4.D shows that $\operatorname{Proj} S_{m\bullet}\cong \operatorname{Proj} S_{\bullet}$, and we have a similar isomorphism for $R_{\bullet}$. Thus, $\operatorname{Proj} S_{\bullet}\cong \operatorname{Proj} R_{\bullet}$ and we are done.

Now I'm also not sure if this solutions works, because I don't seem to be using the "finitely generated" hypothesis anywhere in my above "proof". I would be glad if someone would point out what I am missing.

Comment: “Same” probably means isomorphic.

Comment: I'm making this a comment instead of an answer because I don't know what I'm talking about. But it seems like the preceding definition of $S_{n \bullet}$ is only made for finitely generated $S_\bullet$ in the first place. Could it be that the definition does not work, or is ill-behaved somehow, if $S_\bullet$ is not finitely generated? (Either way, it's possible that Exercise 6.4.D assumes $S_\bullet$ is finitely generated, because otherwise we haven't defined what $S_{n \bullet}$ is.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov You're correct that the previous definition is only made for fg $S_\bullet$, but [the proposition is true in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853754/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list, your solution is totally correct and does not need the finite generation hypothesis (see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853754/construct-the-isomorphism-from-operatornameproj-a-to-operatornameproj-a)). As Misha Lavrov points out in the comments, Vakil has only made his definition of $S_{n\bullet}$ for finitely generated $S_\bullet$, which is why the question is stated as it is.