# If $\operatorname{Proj} S$ is noetherian, must $S$ be noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Suppose $S$ is a positively graded ring, and $S$ is generated by $S_1$ (the degree $1$ part of $S$). If we know $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is Noetherian, can we deduce $S$ is a Noetherian ring? Could you give a proof or give a counterexample?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is false. Let $S$ be the graded ring given by $S_0=\Bbb Z$ and $S_d=\Bbb C[x]_d$ for $d>0$. Then $\operatorname{Proj} S\cong \operatorname{Proj} \Bbb C[x]$ ([ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853754/construct-the-isomorphism-from-operatornameproj-a-to-operatornameproj-a)), so $\operatorname{Proj} S\cong \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$, a point. But $S_+$ is not finitely generated for cardinality reasons: any finite collection of generators of $S_+$ give at most countably many elements of $S_+\cap S_1$, and $S_1$ is uncountable.